# validate dynamic input vanilla js

Tags: javascript

It should be noted that, the quantity of the second tab with price input is created dynamically when adding from the first tab.

1 When adding an element of the first tab and if the save button is pressed, an alert "there are 2 empty fields" should be sent.

2 The save button should be disabled, until an item is added to the tabs-one. When an element is added to tabs-two, just enable the button and when this element is clicked, an alert "there are 3 empty fields" should pop up
Just filled all the entries, what needs to be done for now must be executed, say when the button is clicked, send an alert with the following message "Fields full"

3 When adding an element in the table of tab two, when the button is clicked it should say that there are 3 empty fields and if another element is added, it should increase, saying "there are 4 empty fields" and so on if they are added more elements to the second table

4 on the button, if you write to any empty input, this amount should decrease and every time you press the save button, it should say "there are n empty inputs".
when pressing the save button, also when clicking, the focus must be placed on the first empty input

```js
function updateCantidadNuevo(input) {
  if(input.checkValidity()){
   input.setAttribute("data-oldvalue", input.value);
  }
  else{
    input.value = input.getAttribute("data-oldvalue") || input.min;
  }
}
function add(id, cantidad=1){
  let input = tbody.querySelector('.ItemCarrito>.form__element-input_cantidad>#shoppingCartItemQuantity_'+id);
 // input.value= input.valueAsNumber + cantidad;
 if (input === null) {
  // manejar error.
  //console.log('No se logró encontrar el error');
  return;
}

if (typeof input.value === 'undefined' || input.value === null) {
  input.value = cantidad;
} else {
  input.value = (input.valueAsNumber + cantidad);
  // podrias tratar también con
  // input.value = +input.value + cantidad;
  // input.value = +input.value + cantidad ?? cantidad;
}

updateCantidadNuevo(input);
//console.log(id, input);
}


const tbody = document.querySelector('#second-tab >.shoppingCartItemsContainer > #form2 >#tabla >.tbody')



const addToShoppingCartButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#first-tab > #articulos > tbody > tr > .td > .button')

addToShoppingCartButtons.forEach((addToCartButton) => {
  addToCartButton.addEventListener('click', addToCartClicked);

});



function addToCartClicked(event) {
  const button = event.target;
 
  
  const item = button.closest('.tr');

  const id_prod = item.querySelector('.id_n').textContent;


  const cantidad_disponible = item.querySelector('.cantidad_disponible').textContent;
  const talla = item.querySelector('.talla').textContent;

  
  addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod, cantidad_disponible, talla);
}
function addItemToShoppingCart(id_prod,cantidad_disponible,talla) {
    

 
  const elementsTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('title');

  for (let i = 0; i < elementsTitle.length; i++) {
    if (elementsTitle[i].innerText === id_prod) {
    
      return;
    }
  }

  const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    tr.classList.add('ItemCarrito')
     tr.setAttribute("id", `tr_${id_prod}`);

  Content = `
     <th scope="row">${id_prod}</th>

     <td class="table__productos">
     <input id="id_productos_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${id_prod}" class="id_productos"
    style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">

       <h6 id="title_${id_prod}" class="title" hidden>${id_prod}</h6>
     </td>

    

    
     <td class="table__cantidad_disponible">
     <input id="cantidad_disponible_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${cantidad_disponible}" class="cantidad_disponible"
     style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;" >
      
    </td>

    <td class="table__talla">
    <input id="talla_${id_prod}" type="text" value="${talla}" class="talla"
   style="border: none; border-color: transparent;outline: 0;width: 40px;">
      
     </td>

    



    
    
    <td class="form__element-input_cantidad">
                <input id="shoppingCartItemQuantity_${id_prod}" max="${cantidad_disponible}"  class="shopping-cart-quantity-input cantidad" type="number"
                    value="1" min="1">
                
                </td>

        <td class="form__element-input_precio">
     <input  id="precio_${id_prod}" type="text" class="precio"     min="0">
      
     </td>

     <td class="table__delete">
     <button class="delete btn btn-danger">x</button>
      
    </td>

     `
   
    
   tr.innerHTML = Content 
     tbody.append(tr)
    }






window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
            const form = document.getElementById("form2");
            const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");
            const botonGuardar = document.getElementById("guardardatos");

            form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
                event.preventDefault();
                // Aquí puedes realizar las acciones necesarias al enviar el formulario
            });

            inputs.forEach((input) => {
                input.addEventListener("input", validarFormulario);
            });

            validarFormulario();

            function validarFormulario() {
                let camposVacios = 0;

                inputs.forEach((input) => {
                    if (input.value.trim() === "") {
                        camposVacios++;
                    }
                });

                if (camposVacios > 0) {
                    botonGuardar.disabled = true;
                    botonGuardar.value = `Hay ${camposVacios} campos vacíos`;
                } else {
                    botonGuardar.disabled = false;
                    botonGuardar.value = "Guardar";
                }
            }
        });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled-2</title>
  
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.8.0/css/bulma.min.css">
   
</head>
<body>



  

<section class="section">
      <div class="tabs">
         <ul class="tabs-menu">
          <li class="is-active" data-target="first-tab"><a>Tab one</a></li>
          <li data-target="second-tab"><a>Tab two</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content" id="first-tab">

      <table id="articulos"class="table">
        <thead>
           
            <tr>
            
            <TH>id </TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>
                <TH>Añadir</TH>
              <TH>Añadir</TH>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody  id="productos_content">
             <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">15<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 3</td>
            <td class="talla"> 36</td>
              
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(15)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
  
        </tr> 
       
       <tr class="tr">
         
            
            <td class="id_n">1<td>
            <td class="cantidad_disponible"> 7</td>
            <td class="talla"> 40</td>
          
<td class="td"><button id="15" onclick="add(1)"   class="button">Añadir</button></td>
    
        </tr> 
        </tbody>
        </table>
    
          </div>



      <div class="tab-content" id="second-tab">
      <div class="shopping-cart-items shoppingCartItemsContainer">
      <form id="form2" >
<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo"class="form-control" required>
                
                    <input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
<input type="submit" id="guardardatos" value="Guardar"  />
   

      <table id="tabla" class="table">
 
            <tr>
            <TH>id</TH>
            <TH>id del producto</TH>   
            <TH>cantidad_disponible</TH>
            <TH>talla zapatos</TH>          
            <TH>cantidad </TH>
            <TH>precio </TH>
            </tr>
               <tbody id="carrito_content" class="tbody">
               
        </tbody>
    </table>

      <div class="float-right">
      Total:<input type="text" id="resultado_total" value="0" disabled > </input>

        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>

<script>
    const tabSystem = {
    init(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-menu').forEach(tabMenu => {
            Array.from(tabMenu.children).forEach((child, ind) => {
                child.addEventListener('click', () => {
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                });
                if(child.className.includes('is-active')){
                    tabSystem.toggle(child.dataset.target);
                }
            });
        });
    },
    toggle(targetId){
        document.querySelectorAll('.tab-content').forEach(contentElement=>{
            contentElement.style.display = contentElement.id === targetId ? 'block' : 'none';
            document.querySelector(`[data-target="${contentElement.id}"]`).classList[contentElement.id === targetId ? 'add' : 'remove']('is-active');
        })
    },
};
// use it
tabSystem.init()
</script>


</html>
```

It works halfway if I add 5 times the 4th is null, it is the closest thing to dynamic input

```js
var counter = 0;
function addInput(divName){
counter++; 
var Ai8ousa = document.createElement('div'); 
 Ai8ousa.innerHTML = "Field: "+(counter +1) + "<input type='text' name='field[]'>";   
document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(Ai8ousa);

}

function validations(form){
var field;
var i=0;
do{
     field=form[i];
       if (field.value=='')
          {
            alert('The field is null!!!');
            return false;
          }
        i++;
}while(i<counter);
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validations(this)" >
<div id="dynamicInput">
Field : <input type="text" name="field[]" />  <br />
</div>
<input type="button" value="New field" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: Your snippet throws a bunch of errors: `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#188:23'>188:23</a> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'valueAsNumber')"` while clicking on "Anadir" and `"Uncaught ReferenceError: CarritoTotalmio is not defined"` while clicking on "Guardar" in tab two.

Comment: Please omit these two errors, I already removed the show console option, I don't want to make the code more extensive, but what you mention I have already corrected

Comment: Include minimal example to reproduce the problem. Not a code dump that fails to run and a list of business requirements.

Comment: @junvar, There is, I added the missing code, it no longer shows an error in the console.